# Wrong number in AH when putting a number in AX

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

So I'm writing a program that inserts 10 numbers in an array like the following: 2, 4, 8, 14, 22... where the number is equaled to the index*2 plus the value of the number on the previous index for example 22 is on position 4; 4*2=8; 8+14=22;

Then the user inputs a two digit number and in the variable A the program places the value of the number on the index which is equaled to the inputted number in the array:

```
.model small
.data

    niza dw 10 dup(?)
    broj db ?
    A dw ?

.code

start:

    mov ax, data
    mov es, ax
    mov ds, ax

    mov bx, 0
    mov niza[bx], 2d

Insert:
    mov cx, niza[bx]
    inc bx
    push bx
    mov ax, bx
    mov bx, 2
    mov dx, 0
    mul bx
    add ax, cx
    pop bx
    mov niza[bx], ax
    cmp bx, 10
    jne Insert

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 48d
    mov bl, 10
    mov dl, 0
    mul bl
    mov broj, al

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 48
    add broj, al

    mov bl, broj
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 0
    mov ax, niza[bx]
    mov A, ax


end start

ends
```

However here is the problem.

The numbers are putted correctly in the array however if i put a number for example 03 instead of placing 14 it places the number 14 it places the number 5646.

After looking around I found out that after I move the value of niza[BX] in AX in the instruction:

```
mov ax, niza[bx]
```

the value inside AX is 14 in AL and 22 in AH and thus computes the total value 5646 and places in the variable.

The 14 in the AL is correct but I have no idea where the 22 in AH comes from.

I can't simply set AH to 0 because if I choose to get from the array a number on a larger index it will give me a larger value larger than 255 that needs both AL and AH so setting AH to 0 after moving the number to ax will change the number.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ax *=2` is *much* more easily done with `add ax,ax`, or `shl ax, 1`.  Never use `mul` for a power of 2, except maybe if you want the high-half result in DX.  Your code is overcomplicated as well as having the bug that Sep pointed out.  You also don't need to reload the old value from memory; just keep that in a register because it's the same as what you stored last iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that, if your *niza* array were defined to contain **bytes**, your program would be correct. Sadly you've defined the array to contain **words** having written:

> ```
> niza dw 10 dup(?)
> ```

The problem lies in your use of the `BX` register. At the same time you use it to count the elements and to address the elements. Counting happens **per 1**, but addressing must happen **per 2** (because of the elements being 2 bytes long each).

The important thing here is that in an instruction such as `mov niza[bx], ax` the `BX` register is not an element index like in the other programming language that you might know, but rather it is a displacement in the array.

```
word-value    index  displacement
  2             0      0
  4             1      2
  8             2      4
 14             3      6
 22             4      8
 32             5     10
 44             6     12
 58             7     14
 74             8     16
 92             9     18
112            10     20
```

This is how to create the array:

```
    mov bx, 0          ; Displacement of first element  
    mov niza[bx], 2
Insert:
    mov ax, niza[bx]
    add bx, 2          ; Displacement of next element
    add ax, bx
    mov niza[bx], ax
    cmp bx, 20
    jne Insert
```

Because in this particular case the displacement is already double the index, you don't need the multiplication times 2.

Similarly you need to modify retrieving the result:

```
    mov bl, broj       ; BROJ is an index
    mov bh, 0
    shl bx, 1          ; but you need a displacement, so double it
    mov ax, niza[bx]
    mov A, ax
```